# How to play the result of "mpc search"?

Tags: mpd

Example:

```
$ mpc search title "when I was your man" 
Bruno Mars/Unorthodox Jukebox/06 Bruno Mars - When I Was Your Man.mp3
```

How do I play the song? I've tried piping it to `mpc play` but no luck.

```
$ mpc search title "when I was your man" | mpc play
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at what `mpd play` is supposed to do:

```
play <position>
  Starts playing the song-number specified. If none is specified, plays number 1.
```

you'll notice that it doesn't really make sense to specify a filename as `position`.

I'm not sure there's an easy way to do what you want with mpc because it doesn't support all commands MPD does (like `addid`).

If you don't want to keep your playlist, you can do

```
mpc clear; mpc search title "when I was your man" | mpc add; mpc play
```

which clears the playlist, adds the song(s) you want and plays the first song in the playlist.

The best I could come up with to play add a song to a playlist without clearing it and playing the song is

```
title="your song title here"
mpc search title $title  | mpc add
mpc playlist -f '%position% %title%' | grep -i $title | head -n1 | cut - -d " " -f 1 | xargs mpc play
```

Comment: You can get the position using `mpc status | sed -n -e '/#/ s/^.*#\([[:digit:]]*\)\/.*$/\1/p'`.

Answer (score 9):

`mpc play` expects a position as argument, not a filename. A position in a playlist to be precise. You first have to `add` the file to a playlist, and then tell `mpc` to `play` that song from the playlist. But `add` will add the new song at the end of the playlist. To `play` the newly added song you have to know how long the playlist is.

Here are some suggestions how you can add a song and start playing it:

1. Clear the playlist first:

   ```
   mpc clear
   mpc search title "when I was your man" | mpc add
   mpc play
   ```
2. Insert as next and play next:

   ```
   mpc search title "when I was your man" | mpc insert
   mpc next
   ```
3. Determine length of playlist to play last:

   ```
   mpc search title "when I was your man" | mpc add
   mpc play $(mpc playlist | wc -l)
   ```

Comment: We can get the number of each song in the current playlist and the song name with: `mpc playlist | awk '{print $0, NR}'`. In my case I already have the song I want, after knowing the song number in the playlist I just run: `mpc play "number"`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way than [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87754/100379) (in case the song is already in your playlist):

```
mpc searchplay filename "$(mpc search title 'when I was your man')"
```

If no result is found, mpc will simply play the first song in your playlist.

If you don't want the output of mpc, just append `2>&1 >/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mpc search function, i've seen what you want done with a 'jump to song' script:
http://th0th.me/log/mpd-music-player-daemon-jump-to-song/

this uses mpc to get a full playlist with 'position', greps this list for the search keywords and sends the corresponding 'position' marker to mpc to play

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for if you are **adding more than one track** (e.g. album) **to the *end***.

We can obtain positions within now playing:

```
position="$(mpc status | sed -n -e '/#/ s/^.*#\([[:digit:]]*\/[[:digit:]]*\).*$/\1/p')"
curr="$(<<< "$position" cut -d/ -f1)"
length="$(<<< "$position" cut -d/ -f2)"
```

Then, simply insert your search result:

```
mpc search title "when I was your man" | mpc insert
```

And play from the beginning of the end:

```
mpc play "$((length + 1))"
```